# What could explain my partitions disappearing on a new SSD with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

So this morning, I had a fresh install of Windows 7 pro, on a new SSD (Patriot TorqX 128gb), which I just put in to a new Dell Studio XPS 9000.  Everything was fine.  I booted to windows, no problem. I go to work.

8 hours later, I come home, and I'm greeted by my boot screen complaining about no bootable devices.

Windows repair from the Windows 7 pro disk says it can't fix the problem.  It doesn't see any windows installs.

I boot up GParted, and my SSD is completely unallocated. No space used, no partitions.

Perhaps this is related to allowing windows 7 to create a utility partition when I installed?  Only thing I can think of.

Is there some kind of known hardware issue that can result in an SSD completely wiping itself?

Answer (score 0):

The utility (100 Meg) partition of Windows 7 is perfectly good and used for the bootloader.

I have not seen this problem before and have used a few SSD's recently, but not that model.

I suggest you look to see if a firmware update is available and if not, it is possible you have a defective unit.

Comment: Firmware came at the latest revision, so I guess I'm looking at RMAing the drive at this point.